# Creating a large number of AWS EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing

This is probably too simple a question, but how does one create many instances (in the low hundreds).

Our process can require up to ten instance/task and we can need to run up to a dozen instances.

However, the upper limit of instances we can run/account is 10-20.

Up until now, we have gone around this with multiple AWS accounts, which is creaky to say the least. We would prefer something more like a large cluster.

Is there a way of upping the limit programmatically, or does one have to make a special AWS request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All accounts have a default limit of around 20 instances. This limit can easily be increased through the AWS console.

You can do this by following these steps: 
-Go to the AWS Console to this link
 https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Limits:
-Click Request limit increase for each instance type you want increased
-You'll need to do this for each region

Provided you don't submit a crazy high limit request (1000) instances, your request should be approved automatically within a few minutes.

See the Docs for more info EC2 limits:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_ec2

Comment: That's what I suspected.  Thanks.

Comment: @SzS AWS will approve your limit requests, usually within 24hrs. Also, you may want to consider using spot instances.